# Is there an installer that has .NET 3.5 SP1 from scratch?

Tags: installation, .net-framework

As I follow it, there's a [full installer for .NET 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en)

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe

And a .[NET 3.5 SP1 installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Also as I follow it, the first of those two links is what you use when you have, say, a clean XP machine with no previous versions of .NET on it (or at least nothing past 1.1). The second link is what you use if you have .NET 3.5 already and just need .NET 3.5 SP1 on top of it.

Is there an installer that assumes you have no previous version of .NET on your machine but also has .NET 3.5 SP1 as well? Or am I wrong and that second link does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second installer will install everything, even if no previous .NET framework exists. (Apart from V1.1)

Comment: Yeah and I have a clean VM in progress to test this, I was just wondering if anyone knew for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second installer link you provided is the full installer for .NET 3.5 SP1. Also do remember to apply the [.NET 3.5 SP1 Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959209) too.